# How to support my custom font with IE11

Tags: html, css, fonts, internet-explorer-11

I have a custom font created by someone else. Let's call it TTM for the purpose of this question. Consequently, there are files like these:

TTM.eot, TTM.ttf

The files are reached and loaded correctly with Chrome and FireFox, but under Internet Explorer 11, I get a bunch of errors and the fonts are not loaded properly.

**Error1**:

> CSS3111: @font-face encountered unknown error. File TTM.eot

This happens several times. Because of the unkown error I do not know what should I do to fix it. The error description is this:

> "@font-face encountered unknown error"   An unknown problem was
>   encountered with the "Web Open Font Format (WOFF)", and "Embedded
>   OpenType font (EOT)" of the Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) font.   Check
>   source of "WOFF" fonts. Try alternate font face or source to see if
>   you can reproduce the problem.

**Error2**:

> CSS3114: @font-face failed OpenType embedding permission check.
>   Permission must be Installable. File: TTM.ttf

Docs:

> "@font-face failed OpenType embedding permission check. Permission
>   must be Installable."   The font-face doesn't have permissions to
>   install with the current webpage.   Get the correct permission or
>   licenses for embedding the font.

This happens twice. This is something about some kind of permission. From the errors what could be the problem and what could be the fix?

EDIT:

As it was asked for in the comment section, I add the relevant CSS part:

```
    @font-face {
        font-family: TTM;
        src: url(../../Fonts/TTM.eot?v1); /* EOT file for Internet Explorer */
    }

    @font-face {
        font-family: TTM;
        src: url(../../Fonts/TTM.ttf?v1); /* TTF file for CSS3 browsers */
    }
```

Comment: The `eot` format is supported only by IE and it's really better to use `woff` fonts. Are you sure you wanna stick with the `eot` format? Can you add the `css` definition?

Comment: @Dekel, I have never worked with custom fonts. I would really like to use woff fonts if they solve the issue, but as a matter of fact I am still puzzled with the error messages about permission and unkown errors.

Comment: Can you try [this tool](http://www.derwok.de/downloads/ttfpatch/) to patch your fonts?

Comment: Open the dev tool bar to see what is the request IE send to the server. Maybe the `../../Fonts/TTM.eot?v1` is wrong location

Comment: @Dekel, then it would not load the font in Chrome and FireFox, would it?

Comment: are you talking about `woff` fonts? or what?

Comment: @Dekel, I have no idea. How can I check that?

Comment: also, on your CSS, use `src: url(../../Fonts/TTM.eot?v1) format('embedded-opentype');`

Comment: Open IE, click F+12, check the `network` tab (you might need to click enable network or something like that...) You should be able to see all the requests the website is sending to the server (the request to the eot file is one of them).

Comment: @JeromeIndefenzo, it seems that I have a problem with an eot. Is this patch supporting that as well? And what does it do?

Comment: @JeromeIndefenzo, the `format` you added there is for IE<=8. I really don't think it is relevant for IE11

Comment: `format('embedded-opentype')` could fix your EOT problem. The tool might fix your CSS3114 problem.

Comment: @Dekel oh I see. Then I have no idea what's wrong with the EOT.

Comment: @JeromeIndefenzo, the problem persists if I add that.